# How can remote notification fetch information in background in swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I am looking for a way for my IOS application to exchange information with my server once a remote notification has been received but before the user has taken any action and decided whether he should open the application or not.

In my App Delegate, I have tried something like

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    NSLog("%@ remote notification received ", __FUNCTION__)
     MyServerJSONRPCRequest.getMyStuff();
   completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.NewData)               
   }
```

When the remote notification is received I definitely gets into this but the actual request is never sent to my server, it is sent only if I actually open the app from the application.

Possible explanation : has it anything to do with the fact the request is asynchronous?

2nd possible explanation : I do not have any clue about the right usage of  UIBacgkroundFetchResult

Comment: Have you enabled the Background Mode for Remote Notifications?

Comment: if your app is manually quit, i.e. double click home button and slice up. This method will not be called.

Comment: @Clever Error : Yes Background mode is enabled for Remote Notification.

Comment: @zp_x : so that would be the difference with a call to `func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification` with no fetchCompletingHandler argument?

Comment: @YvesNicolas no difference, if the app is quit, the notification wont reach your app.

Comment: @zp_x : well strange, I have actually a production app right now which gets the notification by this method even if the app has been sliced up.

Comment: @YvesNicolas from this document: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html?hl=ar#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:  In the discussion section.

Comment: And I have done a test using dev server a few weeks ago, the app was not able to handle the notification if it is force quit. I am also curious how your app did it. Did you open your app from the notification message?